# Java string get the character after space

Tags: java, substring

I was having some problem when trying to compare strings in Java.

Example of list of words to be compared:

```
angry berry you young your apple orange yeast
```

When user entered 'y' character, the results I am getting as text suggestion list:

```
you young your yeast
```

At this point, it is correct. Then I entered 'you '. There is a space afterwards. At this point the text suggestion list should not be coming out. But it did. Then I proceed to enter 'b' so 'berry' should be showing as suggestion list which it did.

I not sure why whenever I entered a space, the suggestion list is still showing. There is something wrong with the sequence. Here is my code:

```
String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();

// getting text after space
String[] segments = input.split(" ");
String lastInputSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];

// if user input not null, proceed to find matching keywords
if(!lastInputSegment.equals("")) {
      // find matching keywords
      // display list of matching keywords
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what "text suggestion list" ? shouldn't you use ", " as separator in the split call?

Comment: When you say "the results I am getting", what do you mean? There is no result output in your code.

Comment: it is a list with matching keywords. I am trying to do like google keyboard whereby I enter first word followed by space and second word. then the text suggestion list should be based on the second word only instead of concatenation of first + second word

Comment: But `you `, with a space at the end, doesn't match any of your data.  Can you show us data with multiple words which explains what you are trying to do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Okay first I entered 'y', it should show the list of words starting with 'y'. Then I selected 'you'. And I added a space afterwards. By this time, the suggestion list with all the words starting with 'y' should not be showing. But it did. Then I proceed to enter 'b'. The 'berry' should show in the suggestion list.

Comment: I am sorry for bad explanation but that's more or less for the sequence. I am trying to do like if the last character is a space, don't do anything. if it is a character, grab it

Comment: @guest176969 The problem with that logic is a keyword followed by a space _should_ match any two (or 3, etc.) word terms which start with that keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `input.split(" ")` which splits on a whitespace, causing the trailing whitespace to be removed and thus it still finds the String.

Example:

```
Input: "you something"
Becomes: ["you", "something"]
```

So following that:

```
Input: "you "
Becomes: ["you"]
```

If you do want to keep the empty string, you can do the following:

```
String[] segments = input.split(" ", -1);
```

A negative value for split indicates that it should not ignore the empty strings.
Please note that this will cause **all** the whitespaces between the words to be preserved.

Comment: Any ideas how to overcome it?

Comment: You mean how you can keep the trailing whitespace? For what purpose do you want to use that?

Comment: As in I wanted to do something like if the last character is a white space, I don't do anything. If it is a character, I proceed to find matching keyword. But each matching keyword is based on the last segment of text after the white space

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pattern matching as part of your search logic, then regex would seem to be a good option.  We can easily handle this using streams and `String.matches`:

```
String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();
String[] segments = input.split(" ");
String search = "you ";

Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(segments);
stream.filter(s -> s.matches(search + ".*"))
    .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If the behavior you want to is to ignore all trailing whitespace on the search term, however many words it might be, then you can simply call `String.trim()` on the search term:

```
String search = "you ";
search = search.trim();
// then use the same logic above
```

Comment: You could improve your snippet, by compiling a `Pattern` before the streaming and then create a `Matcher` for every string

Comment: @Lino That actually looks very non trivial to do (I've never done it myself).  Maybe you could post another answer with that implementation.  But I agree that it would be optimal to not keep building a pattern each time if we could avoid it.

Comment: @Lino Actually, it's above on my screen. Anyway, I threw you an upvote.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the helps, really appreciated them!!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `Scanner` instead of `String.split()`.

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(editInputText())) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String item = sc.next(); // add filter here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helps!!

Answer (score 0):

[@Tim Biegelseisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50903953/5515060)s answer works very well. But you can improve it by using `Pattern`s, because `String.matches()` always creates a pattern and a matcher itself.

From the jdk1.8.0_131 sources of `String.matches()`:

```
public boolean matches(String regex) {
    return Pattern.matches(regex, this);
}
```

Source of `Pattern.matches()`:

```
public static boolean matches(String regex, CharSequence input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}
```

So by using the following snippet you get rid of creating a new `Pattern` for every input string you're iterating over:

```
String input = "angry berry you young your apple orange yeast";
Pattern search = Pattern.compile("you .*");   // our search pattern

Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(input)     // creates a Stream<String>
    .filter(s -> search.matcher(s).matches()) // checks if string matches
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @Downvoter may want to explain why you chose not to find this answer useful?